# Retrofit. POST with request body without response body

Tags: android, kotlin

I try to POST these login and password

```
{
    "userLogin": "Mark",
    "userPassword": "Pencil"
}
```

According to POSTMAN, where I put above JSON as a raw code, I got an empty response body and response code: 200 (Logging is succesful). But I can't achieve it in Android Studio. Here is an API interface

```
interface LoginService {
    @POST("login")
    fun userLogin(
        @Query("userLogin") userLogin: String,
        @Query("userPassword") userPassword: String
    ):Call<Void>
}
```

And here is Retrofit:

```
fun checkLoginData() {
        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("myurl...")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
        val service = retrofit.create(LoginService::class.java)
        val call = service.userLogin("Mark", "Pencil")

        call.enqueue(object : Callback<Void>{
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<Void>, response: Response<Void>) {
            if(response.code() == 200){
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Logged in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            }
        }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<Void>, t: Throwable) {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

    })
}
```

I suppose that my `LoginService` is created incorrectly because there is always onFailure response. How should I do it rightly?

Comment: Show your response on Postman and why you put call back void ?

Comment: Pass @body for raw json

Comment: @Ashish I use call back void because response body is empty. Postman shows empty body and Status: 200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using POST you'll probably not use @Query, but rather a @Body. E.g.

```
data class LoginRequest(
val userLogin: String,
val userPassword: String
)
```

and in your interface :

```
 @POST("login")
    fun userLogin(@Body request: LoginRequest):Call<Void>
```

EDIT:
Since it's an issue with ClearText:
You need to add `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` to your AndroidManifest.
Refer to 
[Android 8: Cleartext HTTP traffic not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted)
Option 2 for more info.

Comment: could you paste the throwable's stacktrace?

Comment: I've got this error `CLEARTEXT communication to 'myUrl' not permitted by network security policy`

Comment: Working perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use @Body instead of @Query

```
  @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
  @POST("login")
  fun userLogin(@Body rawParams: String):Call<Void>
```

Then you can create parameter like this

```
  val params= JSONObject()
  params.put("userLogin","Mark")
  params.put("userPassword","Pencil")
```

Last change in

```
 val call = service.userLogin(params.toString())
```

Error Solution for cleartext is 
Create file

```
   res/xml/network_security_config.xml

   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <trust-anchors>
        <certificates src="system" />
    </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
    </network-security-config>
```

And Then Add in Manifest

```
 <application 
      android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
    ...>
```